# How to store and conveniently check the insertion time of time series data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a question, how to save the insertion time of data writing into Apache IoTDB? Some data are uploaded late and we need to mark them. There are many measuring points in my case, so if I stored the receiving time in a separate column, it is not convenient for me to query. I want to know are there any other ways to conveniently check the data that are delayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use triggers in Apache IoTDB. When writing data, compare the insertion time with the collection time. If it is later than a certain threshold, set it to store to other time series. There's only two columns in this kind of time series, the original time series name and timestamp. It is equivalent to making an inverted index, so you can find the specific data that is late according to this index.